# How to save my generated QR code image?

Tags: javascript

I am in process of learning.I wanted to try an qrcode generator project.The project works fine.I have two small doubts.Can someone suggest me anything,It would be very helpful.Thank you guys.

1.How can I save my generated QR code image ?

2.How to set a limit for data entry ? (i mean to set a limit for the value to be entered in the code)

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
<head>
     <title>QRCode generator </title>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
     <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="qrcode.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
     <input id="text" type="string" value={"foo":"35"};  style="width:80%" /><br />
     <div id="qrcode" style="width:100px; height:100px; margin-top:20px;"></div>

     <script type="text/javascript">
     var qrcode = new QRCode(document.getElementById("qrcode"), {
        width: 150,
        height: 150,
        colorDark: "#1b1076",
        colorLight: "#ffffff",
     });

    function makeCode() {
        var elText = document.getElementById("text");

        if (!elText.value) {
            alert("Input a text");
            elText.focus();
            return;
        }

        qrcode.makeCode(elText.value);
    }

    makeCode();

    $("#text,#color").
    on("blur", function() {
        makeCode();
    }).
    on("keydown", function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            makeCode();
        }
    });

   </script>
   </body>
```

Comment: Use your browser's debug mode to explore the DOM and find out what kind of element your QR code is - SVG? PNG? Canvas? HTML table? Then search SO for questions like "Save image from HTML canvas", "Limit length of HTML input field". Then if you really can't find these, create them -- they are two separate, focused  questions.

Comment: Print screen and paint to crop is always an option.